# Django PostgreSQL FTS

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to build a web-site using Django 2.0 and PostgreSQL 9.6, the main idea of which is to enable users to search through stored documents via Full Text Search (FTS) tools on many fields.

For example I have such models:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=1024, default='<Empty>')
    text = models.TextField()

class DocumentAttachment(models.Model):
    belong_to = models.ForeignKey('Document', related_name='attachments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.Charfield(max_length=1024, default='<Empty>')
    image = models.ImageField()
```

I'd like to use FTS on fields `Document.name`, `Document.text`, `DocumentAttachment.name`. And also, it would be great to provide user with tokens of matched strings (and in which `model.field`).

The database expected to reach more then 10 000 documents, so, as I understand it's nice practice to use indexes.

Could you give me some tips, how to implement this?
Do I have to use "class Meta" approach or create a new model with aggregated text fields?
Do I have to use TrigramSimilarity, and how?

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest code you can have to perform a [full-text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+postgresql+full-text-search) in Django with PostgreSQL on your models:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

Document.objects.annotate(
    search=(
        SearchVector('name') +
        SearchVector('text') +
        SearchVector(StringAgg('attachments__name', delimiter=' ', distinct=True))
    )
).filter(search='Test')
```

For all the basic **documentation** on using the [full-text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+postgresql+full-text-search) in Django with PostgreSQL you can use the official documentation: **"[Full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)"**

If you want to deepen further you can read an **article** that I wrote on the subject:

**"[Full-Text Search in Django with PostgreSQL](http://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql)"**